# How to 'react' to the response of a request using Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using Python requests to get information from the mobile website of the german railways company (https://mobile.bahn.de/bin/mobil/query.exe/dox')

For instance:

```
import requests
query = {'S':'Stuttgart Hbf', 'Z':'München Hbf'}
rsp = requests.get('https://mobile.bahn.de/bin/mobil/query.exe/dox',  params=query)
```

which in this case gives the correct page.

However, using the following query:

```
query = {'S':'Cottbus', 'Z':'München Hbf'}
```

It gives another response, where the user is required to choose one of the given options (The server is confused about the starting stations, since there are many beginning with 'Cottbus')

Now, my question is: given this response, how can I choose one of the given options, and then repeat the request without getting this error ?

I tried to look at the cookies, to use a session instead of a simple get request. But nothing worked so far.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: I check the website, it seems use post to send the options. so you need to post the corresponding data to website.

Comment: This is true. But this does not solve the problem. My problem is specific to 'Cottbus' (see my comment below for a better understanding of the problem)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Beautifulsoup to parse the response and get the options if there is a select on the response:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

query = {'S': u'Cottbus', 'Z': u'München Hbf'}
rsp = requests.get('https://mobile.bahn.de/bin/mobil/query.exe/dox',  params=query)
soup = BeautifulSoup(rsp.content, 'lxml')

# check if has choice dropdown
if soup.find('select'):
    # Get list of tuples with text and input values that you will nee do use in the next POST request
    options_value = [(option['value'], option.text) for option in soup.find_all('option')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be more specific, the problem is given in the example above. When choosing 'Cottbus' as the starting station, the first option given is also named 'Cottbus' ! So by making a new request with the same name, nothing changes. This however is not the case in Chrome for instance. Once an option choosed (even if it has the same name as the originally given station), it works ! So, I am trying to imitate Chrome but could not find how so far !

Comment: If you want to automate exactly the behavior of a browser, look for Selenium Webdriver

Comment: So there is no simpler solution using the requests package ?

Comment: @AhmedAyadi, using only requests, I think not. I still think you can solve this using my method, using beautifulsoup. To know if you got the right results, you can find the element where the train schedule is. If you dont find it, do what I say in this answer